# How to access a variable in Jsonnet if it's in a nested dictionary?

Tags: json, variables, scope, jsonnet

My goal is to make values of inner fields accessible to outer fields in a nested dictionary.

Let's say I have the following code

```
diction: {
  "outer": "part1",
    {
      "inner": "part2"
    }
  "outer and inner": outer + inner 

}
```

The above code doesn't work since inner is not accessible due to scoping. I want to do something like global

```
diction: {
  "outer": "part1",
    {
      global "inner": "part2"
    }
  "outer and inner": outer + inner 

}
```

or find a way to make jsonnet variables mutable so I can still modify a variable to extract the value of inner.

```
diction: {
  "outer": "part1",
  "outer and inner": "",
    {
      "inner": "part2",
      "outer and inner": outer + inner
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your `jsonnet` scriplets are not syntactically correct: you should *not* think `jsonnet` as a "standard" imperative language with "inner" scopes, but really as a "programmable JSON" instead, to heavily over-simplify it.

As such, the structure (/schema) of `jsonnet` programs is rather close(r) to [JSON syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp), nevertheless *please* do read https://jsonnet.org/learning/tutorial.html and related language material.

Recrafting your original question to be syntactically correct, you can refer to current object's scope using `self`, then use dot notation to refer to contained objects' fields:

### code

```
{
  diction: {
    outer: 'part1',
    // NB: `in1` is an object (in jsonnet terms), with key:value entries such as `inner`
    in1: {
      inner: 'part2',
    },
    'outer and inner': self.outer + self.in1.inner,
  },
}
```

### output

```json
{
   "diction": {
      "in1": {
         "inner": "part2"
      },
      "outer": "part1",
      "outer and inner": "part1part2"
   }
}
```

Note that if you want to void `outer` and `in1` fields from manifesting in JSON output, you can use the double-colon notation as `outer::` and `in1::`.